# Install xdebug for php 5.3.17 on centos 6.3 (final)

Tags: php, centos, yum, rpm, xdebug

I'm really having difficulty finding out how to install xdebug for php 5.3.17 on centos 6.3.

I've tried [this link](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) (for centos 5.6 admittedly) but had no luck.

Can anyone point to the right RPM repository or yum command please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

The EPEL and REMI repo contains xdebug for php. I suggest you try them instead.

Their package name is: `php-pecl-xdebug`, so you can just go with `yum install php-pecl-xdebug`

Also, for further reference on xdebug availability:
http://pkgs.org/download/php-pecl-xdebug

Comment: Hi, thanks for post, however recieves this error:   
Error: Package: php-pecl-xdebug-2.0.5-1.el5.1.i386 (epel)
           Requires: php-api = 20041225
           Installed: php-common-5.3.17-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
               php-api = 20090626
               php-api = 20090626-x86-32
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.i686 (base)
               php-api = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.i686 (updates)
               php-api = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: @GHarping, Um... wasn't implying that you should get both epel and remi and active both. Just that you should try one of them. REMI contains very new packages, and because you have php-common from remi, you cannot install other php components that depends on php-common from older versions like epel. You can remove one of the repos and uninstall, then reinstall them or you can set yum priorities to set precedence for one of them.

Comment: I didn't know there was a choice between, or even what either are. I shall explore further. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

pecl install xdebug

http://xdebug.org/docs/install

As of Xdebug 0.9.0 you can install Xdebug through PEAR/PECL. This only works with with PEAR version 0.9.1-dev or higher and some UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install from RPM then the question is from where do you have PHP, from which repo, since CentOS doesn't ship 5.3.17.
Otherwise just `pecl install xdebug` as others pointed out.